# How to improve time of python code with database queries

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, django

I have some database queries in Django 1.11 which takes about 40 seconds and I want to improve the speed, but my ideas are going out.
I want to create a Chart with 6 graphs with the data without having to wait 40 seconds.

This is The Model:

```
from django.db import models

class MinutenReserveLastYear(models.Model):
    datum = models.DateField()
    produkt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grenz_lp = models.FloatField()
    mittl_lp = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['datum', 'produkt']),
        ]
```

I make an Ajax request to get the Data:

```
var neg_last_year = $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "/prognose/minutenreserve/data/",
     data: { "produkt": "NEG", "zeitraum": "last_year" },
     dataType: "json",
     context: this
});
```

The view function to get the Data from database:

```
from .models import MinutenReserveLastYear

def minutenreserve_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    produkt_group = request.POST.get("produkt")
    zeitraum = request.POST.get("zeitraum")
    datum_list = {}
    grenz_lp = {}
    mittl_lp = {}

    if zeitraum == "last_year":
        if produkt_group == "NEG":
            produkt_list = ["NEG_00_04", "NEG_04_08", "NEG_08_12", "NEG_12_16", "NEG_16_20", "NEG_20_24"]
            dataset = MinutenReserveLastYear.objects
            last_year = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(datetime.datetime.timestamp(
                datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=52))).year
            days = (datetime.date(last_year, 12, 31) - datetime.date(last_year, 1, 1)).days
            for j in range(6):
                grenz_lp[j] = []
                mittl_lp[j] = []
                datum_list[j] = []
                produkt = produkt_list[j]
                for i in range(days+1):
                    datum = datetime.date(last_year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
                    datum_list[j] += [datum.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')]
                    grenz_lp[j] += [dataset.filter(datum=datum, produkt=produkt).values_list()[0][3]]
                    mittl_lp[j] += [dataset.filter(datum=datum, produkt=produkt).values_list()[0][2]]
            data = {'datum_list': datum_list, 'grenz_lp': grenz_lp, 'mittl_lp': mittl_lp}
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

And when the Ajax request is done:

```
$.when(neg_last_year).done(function(data) {
    var datum_list = data.datum_list[0];
    var grenzlp_00_04 = data.grenz_lp[0];
    var grenzlp_04_08 = data.grenz_lp[1];
    var grenzlp_08_12 = data.grenz_lp[2];
    var grenzlp_12_16 = data.grenz_lp[3];
    var grenzlp_16_20 = data.grenz_lp[4];
    var grenzlp_20_24 = data.grenz_lp[5];
    var neg_last_year = document.getElementById('NEG_LAST_YEAR').getContext('2d');
    var chart_neg_last_year = new Chart(neg_last_year, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: datum_list,
            datasets: [datasets]
            },
            options: options
        })
});
```

I suspect that the problem is somewhere in the many database queries through the loops. How can I speed up the code?
How can I reduce the number of database queries?

Edit:

I tried to improve the speed by using

`dataset = MinutenReserveLastYear.objects.prefetch_related("grenz_lp", "mittl_lp")`
but that did not help.

Comment: Why did you use `prefetch_related` for fields which are not `ForeignKey` fields?

Comment: That was only a try, i do not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are running queries in the loop. What you can do is to get all objects in one query and then filter the objects using `if-else` in the loops.

**Solution**:

```
dataset = MinutenReserveLastYear.objects.all()

for j in range(6):
    grenz_lp[j] = []
    mittl_lp[j] = []
    datum_list[j] = []
    produkt = produkt_list[j]
    for i in range(days+1):
        datum = datetime.date(last_year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=i)

        for data in dataset:
            if data.datum == datum and data.produkt == produkt:
                grenz_lp[j].append(data.grenz_lp)
                mittl_lp[j].append(data.mittl_lp)
```

Comment: wow, this solution is incredible. The Data is instantly ready, from 40 sec. to < 1 sec. Thank you very much.